# CORS issue after migrating to HTTPS with Cloudflare

Tags: django, nginx, cloudflare, django-csrf

I recently migrated my Django project to HTTPS using Cloudflare. While it worked flawlessly with HTTP, I'm now encountering `CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.` issues after the migration. When I tried logging into the admin panel

```
     CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
     ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
     CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
         "https://example-domain.live",
         "https://www.example-domain.live",
         "www.example-domain.live
     ]     
    CORS_CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
    USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = True
    SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I can't recreate this on my local, but have you also added the middleware and `CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS` list as instructed in this [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/)?

Comment: Glad it is fixed. Could you please explain what exactly fixed your issue so others can also benefit from this post?

Comment: I used your solution, forgot to add the csrf_trusted_orgins